# in Docker container firewalld status keep showing me the Error (No icmptypes found)

Tags: centos, docker, firewalld

i'm using Docker in Linux (Centos7)
and container OS is Centos8

when i typed

"systemctl status firewalld" in Docker container

it Active well but showing me the error below

```
ERROR: No icmptypes found.
ERROR: 'python-nftables' failed: internal:0:0-0: Error: Could not process rule: Operation not permitted
internal:0:0-0: Error: Could not process rule: Operation not permitted
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to run docker container with high privileges?
It seems to me that container image you are using is minimal and might not include some "redundant" packages, so you might install them manually and fix dependencies or left as it is.

Comment: thks for u r comment !

Comment: If you don't mind I will repost comment as an answer in order to gain reputation :)

Answer (score 1):

be aware that container image you are using is minimal and might not include some "redundant" packages, so you might install them manually and fix dependencies or left as it is.